# Images in Email Subject

Tags: magento-1.7, email, model, email-templates

I need to unicode "images" (icons) in the subject, for example, to display this image [☮], I can use the following code with the `core/email` model.

```
$subject='☮';
$mailModel=Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mailModel->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=')
```

However the following code (for the `core/email_template` model) is not working,

```
$_mailModel = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$_mailModel->setTemplateSubject('=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=');
```

it returns `=?utf-8?B?SG93IHdhcyB5b3VyIG9yZGVyPyBKdXN0IGNoZWNraW5nIGluLi4u4pmlIFBMVVIg4piuIA==?=`

How to display the image using the second `core/email_template` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just add the template subject without encoding it:

```
$_mailModel = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$_mailModel->setTemplateSubject('How was your order? Just checking in...♥ PLUR ☮');
```

Here is why I think it should work.
The e-mail is sent from `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send()`. This method uses an instance of Zend_Mail. See this line: `$mail = $this->getMail();`. The method `getMail()` looks like this:

```
public function getMail()
{
    if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
        $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    }
    return $this->_mail;
}
```

And later on the subject is set on the `$mail` object:

```
$mail->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables)) . '?=');
```

and this encodes it so there is no need for you to encode the value you set.
If the subject is a simple text, then `getProcessedTemplateSubject` will return it as it is. That method is used to parse the short codes in the subject (`{{var ...}}`).